# Javascript creates the POST, the Symfony controller handles it and redirects, but the new page is not shown

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, fancytree

I'm a beginner in Symfony, PHP and Javascript. I'm struggling with a Javascript tree form based on Fancytree. Thanks to the forum, I made everything working up to POSTing back the form data to the controller, handling the request and redirecting to a success page. The problem is that the success page never shows. Nor IE neither Firefox debuggers show errors. I don't progress anymore, I'm stuck.

Here is my controller:

```
namespace Solar\DataBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Test data sent to Twig and javascript tree
     * 
     * @Route("/form_tree_demo", name="form_tree_demo")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function formTreeDemoAction(Request $request)
    {
        $test = 'Test string';
        $testArray =
        array(
            array(
                'name'=> '1',
                'title' => '1',
                'children' =>
                array(
                    array('name' => '1.1',
                        'title' => '1.1'
                    ),
                    array('name' => '1.2',
                        'title' => '1.2'
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                'name'=> '2',
                'title' => '2',
                'children' =>
                array(
                    array('name' => '2.1',
                        'title' => '2.1'
                    ),
                    array('name' => '2.2',
                        'title' => '2.2'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Post to the controller'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            //for debug
            //throw new Exception(var_dump($form->getData()));

            return $this->redirectToRoute('success', array('message' => 'Post handled'));
        } 

        return $this->render('formtreedemo.html.twig',
            array(
                'tree_form' => $form->createView(), 
                'test_array' => json_encode($testArray)
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/success", name="success")
     */
    public function successAction()
    {
        return $this->render('success.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Here is the Twig form:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>A demo form with Fancytree</h1>
    {{ form_start(tree_form) }}
        <div id="tree" name="selNodes">
        </div>
        Additional data: <input type="text" name="otherFormData" /><br><br>
    {{ form_end(tree_form) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('assets/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="skinSheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendor/fancytree/src/skin-lion/ui.fancytree.css')}}" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('assets/vendor/fancytree/src/jquery.fancytree.js')}}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#tree").fancytree({
                checkbox: true,
                selectMode: 2,
                source:$.parseJSON('{{test_array}}'.replace(/&quot;/ig,'"'))
            });
            $("form").submit(function() {
                $("#tree").fancytree("getTree").generateFormElements();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{path("form_tree_demo")}}",
                    data: formData
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And finally here is the IE console dump :

```
URL                                                         Method  Result  Type                      Initiateur
/web/app_dev.php/form_tree_demo                               GET    200    text/html                 actualiser
/web/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css           GET    200    text/css                  <link rel="stylesheet">
/web/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css     GET    200    text/css                  <link rel="stylesheet">
/web/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js                      GET    200    application/javascript    <script>
/web/assets/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js                     GET    200    application/javascript    <script>
/web/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js             GET    200    application/javascript    <script>
/web/assets/vendor/fancytree/src/skin-lion/ui.fancytree.css   GET    200    text/css                  <link rel="stylesheet">
/web/assets/vendor/fancytree/src/jquery.fancytree.js          GET    200    application/javascript    <script>
/web/app_dev.php/_wdt/115370                                  GET    200    text/html                 XMLHttpRequest
/web/assets/vendor/fancytree/src/skin-lion/icons.gif          GET    200    image/gif                 background-image
/web/app_dev.php/form_tree_demo                               POST   302    text/html                 XMLHttpRequest
/web/app_dev.php/success?message=Post%20handled               GET    200    text/html                 XMLHttpRequest
```

Additional info:
I run Symfony 3.2 under Windows 8, OpenSuse and Ubuntu VM server. Same results everywhere. Same results with deprecated Dynatree also.

Kind help would be appreciated.

Jean-Michel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the success/failure of the ajax and load the new page from there. At present you are returning the html of the redirect call in your controller and your javascript function does not handle the return in any way and just returns false.

If the form in your controller only responds to ajax, then on success pass back the url to redirect to, then get your javascript to perform the redirect.

If the form is only to handle the ajax call, I personally would create a route/function to handle just that.
That why you can perform some checks (like `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()`) to ensure the call is coming from the ajax only.

E.g.

```
public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $form_element1 = $request->request->get('form_element1');
        $form_element2 = $request->request->get('form_element2');
        // do whatever

        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['url'] = $this->generateUrl('new_route');;
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($data);
    }
}
```

Then your javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#tree").fancytree({
                checkbox: true,
                selectMode: 2,
                source:$.parseJSON('{{test_array}}'.replace(/&quot;/ig,'"'))
            });
            $("form").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree").generateFormElements();
                var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{path('ajax_action')}}",
                    data: formData
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    if (data.success === true) {
                        window.location.href = data.url;
                    }
                })
                .fail(function(data) {
                    alert('error');
                })
                .always(function(data) {

                });
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried in the controller : 
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        echo "isXmlHttpRequest";
    }
 It returns Not. The JS alert(error) is trigged. The browser return a white page with: {"success":true,"url":"\/solar\/web\/app_dev.php\/success"}.

Comment: Moreover, in PHP '$form' is empty (data = null).

Comment: @jmichel_ how are you creating your formData in your javascript? Also because you are submitting by ajax the symfony form events are running, hence form being empty. Seperate out the ajax post to it's own route

Comment: OK. Before I try this, please tell me if my approach is correct : I would like to prepare the tree data in  PHP (active nodes, collapsed branches, etc), collects the user updates in JS, send back to PHP and persist the database. Is it the good layout ?

Comment: @jmichel_ that flow is fine, just have one route/function to prepare the data to send to a view and another route/function to process the ajax. On ajax success you can either redirect to another route or just send back the updated html to re-render the html (in javascript), whatever takes your fancy.

Comment: with your solution I got it working. Things are much more clear to me now, many thanks. What next with the thread ? should I post my code, or is it too trivial ?